# How to reallocate content on bigger storage but that the rest of content be zero?

Tags: c++, c

How to reallocate content on bigger storage but that the rest of content be zero ?
I have at the moment like

```
void* oldContent;
size_t oldContentSize;
size_t newBufferSize;

realloc(oldContent, newBufferSize);
```

How to achieve that all with inde from oldContentSize to the end of new buffer have value  '\0' ?

Comment: Your question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141277/how-to-zero-out-new-memory-after-realloc

Comment: If you are on a Windows platform, you can use HeapAlloc/HeapReAlloc instead. Passing the HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY flag will zero the end of the new buffer.

Comment: C **or** C++? C++: use a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void*newContent;
newContent = realloc(oldContent,newBufferSize);
memset(newContent + oldContentSize, 0, newBufferSize - oldContentSize);
```

Comment: This won't compile. Can't do arithmetic on a void pointer.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: gcc permits `void*` arithmetic as an extension (with the unpleasant side effect that `sizeof (void) == 1`). Use one of the `-std=` options to warn about it.

Answer (score 1):

Just have to do it yourself:

```
oldContent = realloc(oldContent, newBufferSize);
memset((char *)oldContent + oldBufferSize, 0, newBufferSize-oldBufferSize);
```

Comment: Don't forget to check that `oldContent != NULL` before calling `memset`. And if `realloc` fails, you've just lost your old pointer value (which may be ok if you're not going to need it again).