# Is it common practice to memset reallocated memory to 0?

Tags: c, memory, idioms

In a C book I found in an example for implementing a dynamically resizing array this code (simplified):

```
void *contents = realloc(array->contents, array->max * sizeof(void *));
array->contents = contents;

memset(array->contents + old_max, 0, array->expand_rate + 1);
```

Source: [Learn C The Hard Way – Chapter 34](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex34.html)

I was a bit surprised what `memset` is supposed to achieve here, but then I understood it's used in order to "zero out" the reallocated memory.

I googled in order to find out, if this is what I'm supposed to do after a `realloc` and found a stackoverflow answer regarding this:

> There is probably no need to do the `memset` […]
>
> But, even if you wanted to "zero it out so everything is nice", or really need the new pointers to be `NULL`: the C standard doesn't guarantee that all-bits-zero is the null pointer constant (i.e., `NULL`), so `memset()` isn't the right solution anyway.

Source: [How to zero out new memory after realloc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141373/132728)

The suggested solution instead of `memset` is then to use a `for` loop in order to set the memory to `NULL`.

So my question is, as `memset` does not necessarily mean setting values to `NULL` and the `for` loop solution seems a bit tedious – is it really needed to set the newly allocated memory?

Comment: IMO this is equivalent to asking about `calloc` vs. `malloc`. If you use `calloc` to allocate and zero memory, then it's consistent to also use `memset` if you need to grow the buffer with `realloc`.

Comment: I find it strange that you've read that you need to use a for loop, to set every value to NULL instead of just zeroing the memory. I think technically NULL does not have to be equal to 0x0. However, in practice you will be hard pressed to find a compiler/system that doesn't do this. (Can someone back this up?)

Comment: Learn C the Hard Way is [not a great resource](http://hentenaar.com/dont-learn-c-the-wrong-way) according to some, and I am inclined to agree. Consider at least reading some other resources as well, e.g. from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/562377/696485) the the SO C book list. Note that if you ever decide to read K&R, read with it in one hand and the errata sheets in the other.

Comment: @RoyT. [NULL has to compare equal to `0` but does not have to be all zero bits](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9894047/696485), although in practice it usually is.

Comment: you should also check return value of realloc, sometimes it fails.

Comment: @RoyT. - It happened on some old systems without memory protection. Physical address 0 could contain operating system info, like interrupt handlers. Having a write to a null pointer overwrite this was a BAD(tm) idea. In that case it might be better to let NULL point to ROM rather than RAM.

Comment: The title question is "is it common practice?" and a final question is "is it really needed?".  The accepted answer answers the 2nd question, but not the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So my question is, as memset does not necessarily mean setting values
>   to NULL and the for loop solution seems a bit tedious – is it really
>   needed to set the newly allocated memory?

`realloc` doesn't initialize values of the newly allocated memory segment.

So it is needed to initialize the memory if you are planning to read values of that (uninitialized) memory. Because reading values from that uninitialized memory will trigger undefined behaviour.

By the way, safe way to use `realloc` (since it can fail) is:

```
  // Since using realloc with size of 0 is tricky and useless probably
  // we use below check (from discussion with @chux)
  if (new_size == 0) 
    dosmth();
  else 
  {
    new_p = realloc(p, new_size);
    if (new_p == NULL)
    {
      // ...handle error
    }else
    {
      p = new_p;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think it makes actualy sense to initialize the memory, because the initial array was allocated with `calloc`.

Comment: @Max: well, as noted the "new part" of the allocated memory will not be initialized, and if you try to read values from that memory you will trigger UB

Answer (score 0):

Setting a `void *` to 0 is a value that will compare equal to `NULL`.  Likely `memset(ptr, 0, size)` is OK - but need to see more code for certainty.

OTOH: is the code correct?  Maybe should be

```
// memset(array->contents + old_max, 0, array->expand_rate + 1);
memset(array->contents + old_max, 0, sizeof(void *) * (array->expand_rate + 1) );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

> But, even if you wanted to "zero it out so everything is nice", or
>   really need the new pointers to be NULL: the C standard doesn't
>   guarantee that all-bits-zero is the null pointer constant (i.e.,
>   NULL), so memset() isn't the right solution anyway.

The C standard does in fact guarantee exactly that.

Per section 6.3.2.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression
>   cast to type `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant*. If a null
>   pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting
>   pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal to
>   a pointer to any object or function.
>
> Conversion of a null pointer to another pointer type yields a null
>   pointer of that type. Any two null pointers shall compare equal.

Note that a pointer with a value of zero is **a** *null pointer*.  That doesn't mean `NULL` itself has to be zero.  But also note that **"any two null pointers shall compare equal"**.  So any *null pointer* is equal to the `NULL` value.

Since `memset()` takes as its second argument an integer value, passing a zero integer value to `memset()` will produce null pointers.  Because the value passed to `memset()` is "[a]n integer constant expression with the value 0", per 6.3.2.3.

Comment: This answer is backwards. The macro `NULL` is guaranteed to be 0 or `(void*) 0`: the null pointer constant.  Its *representation* (which is what the compiler translates `0` into in pointer contexts) is not necessarily all-bits-zero, so `memset` does not guarantee producing null pointers. When you give `0` as an argument to `memset`, it is *not* in a pointer context, and it thus will not be converted to a null pointer. Also see http://www.c-faq.com/null/index.html

Comment: "The macro NULL is guaranteed to be 0 or (void*) 0"  **Authoritative** cite?

Comment: From the ISO C99 spec, section 6.3.2.3 (which you cited): "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant* [55]." combined with footnote 55: "The macro `NULL` is defined ... as a null pointer constant...."

Comment: Furthermore, the section you cited states "If a null pointer **constant** is **converted** to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a **null pointer**..." (emphasis mine).  Your answer mixes up the null pointer *constant* (aka `NULL`, aka 0) with a null pointer (not necessarily all-bits-zero).

Comment: You simply do not understand the standard.  **A** *null pointer constant* is not **THE** *null pointer constant*.  Given that the standard states that **any two null pointers shall compare equal**, there obviously can be more than one *null pointer constant*.  Nothing in the standard requires that any given *null pointer constant* shall be "[a]n integer constant expression with the value 0".  All it does is require that an integer value of 0 be treated **as** a *null pointer constant*.  There's no way to read any of that as "NULL must be zero".

Comment: From the c-faq website you linked to.  http://www.c-faq.com/null/confusion4.html  "Some implementations naturally represent null pointers by special, nonzero bit patterns, particularly when it can be arranged that inadvertently using those values triggers automatic hardware traps. Requiring null pointers to be represented internally as 0, and therefore disallowing use of the special, nonzero values, would be an unfortunate step backwards..."

Comment: Additionally http://www.c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html:  "The Prime 50 series used segment 07777, offset 0 for the null pointer, at least for PL/I. Later models used segment 0, offset 0 for null pointers in C, necessitating new instructions such as TCNP (Test C Null Pointer), evidently as a sop to all the extant **poorly-written C code** which **made incorrect assumptions**."

Comment: But, since the standard does now require that a constant zero value be treated as a null pointer, we *de facto* have reached a situation where zeroing out memory sets pointers to `NULL`, and every implementation I've seen for a long time does define `NULL` as zero.

Comment: No, *you* do not understand the standard.  The **null pointer *constant*** is an expression in C code (`0` or `(void*) 0)`).  The **null pointer** is the machine representation. Everything that you've mentioned in your comments specifically refers to "the null pointer", not "the null pointer constant".  In particular "Some implementations naturally represent null pointers by ... nonzero bit patterns" (note *null pointer*, not *null pointer constant*).  "Any two null pointers shall compare equal": There may be different null pointers for different types, not different *null pointer constants*.

Comment: See http://www.c-faq.com/null/null2.html and http://www.c-faq.com/sx1/index.html#null%20pointer%20constant

Comment: Now, I will agree that the language of the standard does seem to *permit* the existence of other null pointer constants.  Perhaps some implementation could choose to convert `(void*) -1` to a null pointer too and still be compliant.  So you would be correct that `NULL` could be defined to something else.  However, that has no bearing on the use of `memset`, because the conversion between the null pointer constant to a null pointer would not happen.